# Can we define inverse gamma priors in stan_glmer()?

Tags: r, bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, stan, rstan

Although I tried to read the [manual](http://mc-stan.org/rstanarm/articles/priors.html), I don't quite see how I can incorporate the following model in `stan_glmer()`.

$Y_{ij}|\mu_j,\sigma_y \sim N(\mu_j,\sigma_y^2)$

$\mu_j|\mu,\sigma_{\mu} \sim N(\mu,\sigma_{\mu}^2)$ (independent)

$\mu \sim N(50, 16^2)$

$\sigma_y \sim \text{Inverse Gamma}(20,60)$

$\sigma_{\mu} \sim \text{Inverse Gamma}(30,100)$

I saw a similar example with exponential priors [here](https://www.bayesrulesbook.com/chapter-16.html), where the following model was run using the following chunk of codes. If anyone can suggest how I should modify this code to incorporate my priors, it will be very helpful.

$Y_{ij}|\mu_j,\sigma_y \sim N(\mu_j,\sigma_y^2)$

$\mu_j|\mu,\sigma_{\mu} \sim N(\mu,\sigma_{\mu}^2)$ (independent)

$\mu \sim N(50, 52^2)$

$\sigma_y \sim Exp(0.048)$

$\sigma_{\mu} \sim Exp(1)$

```
model_hierarchical <- stan_glmer(
  y ~ (1 | categorical_x), 
  data = d, family = gaussian,
  prior_intercept = normal(50, 2.5, autoscale = TRUE),
  prior_aux = exponential(1, autoscale = TRUE),
  prior_covariance = decov(reg = 1, conc = 1, shape = 1, scale = 1),
  chains = 4, iter = 5000*2, seed = 84735)
```

If there is no option to incorporate inverse gamma priors, then what could be the work around?

Comment: By definition, when a variable has an [Inverse Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution) distribution, its reciprocal has a Gamma distribution.  I hope now the resolution is obvious.

Comment: The resolution is not obvious, to me at least, as it's not possible to use gamma priors either. The *rstanarm* package is somewhat opinionated about priors, so I don't think it's possible to specify inverse gamma prior for the standard deviations. The prior for $\sigma_y$ is given by *prior_aux* and according to the documentation it can be exponential, (half-) normal, student_t or cauchy. See `?stan_glmer`. You could try the *brms* package instead.

Comment: The inverse gamma distribution is not the default prior for reasons. To learn more, you could start [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/41875/237901) or at the [Prior Choice Recommendations](https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/wiki/Prior-Choice-Recommendations) wiki.